# how to deal with nans when using an exponential smoothing function

Tags: matlab

How should nan's be dealt with when using an exponential function in matlab?

For example, I can use an exponential smoothing function as:

```
v = datenum(2008, 1, 1):datenum(2010, 11, 31); % time vector
d = rand(1,length(v)); % data vector

fd = d;
alpha_o = 0.2;
for ii = 2:length(fd);
    fd(ii) = alpha_o.*fd(ii) + (1-alpha_o).*fd(ii-1);
end

plot(v,d); hold on; plot(v,fd);
```

However, if I have a nan in the time series (or many nans as it turns out):

```
d(10) = nan;
```

The smoothed output will then be nan, following the location of nan in the time series.

How should this be dealt with? Should I remove all of the nans and then run the function?

I'm thinking that the point of using an exponential smoothing function with my data is that it provides a smoothed and lagged version of the original series. However, if you have nans which are removed doesn't that lead to errors in your result?

I have seen this post [Using exponential smoothing with NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791737/using-exponential-smoothing-with-nan-values), but it doens't really provide any useful tips that I can apply here.

I also thought of avoiding the nan parts, and say if nan, use the last known smoothed value:

```
fd = d;
alpha_o = 0.2;
for ii = 2:length(fd);
    if isnan(fd(ii)) == 1;
       fd(ii) = fd(ii-1); 
    else
        fd(ii) = alpha_o.*fd(ii) + (1-alpha_o).*fd(ii-1);
    end
end
plot(v,d); hold on; plot(v,fd);
```

Is this the best solution? Not sure what I'd do if the first value was a nan thought...

Comment: The way you treat nans is your choice. You can remove them, you can fill them with interpolated values or you can make your algorithm output NaN for a NaN input. This depends on what your NaNs are and how have been created.

Comment: if you are doing smoothing and interpolating, it is a general practice to remove your NaNs as they will somewhat affect your results.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an appropriate question for StackOverflow. It is very opinion based and dependant on your specific situation and what you are hoping to achieve, which isn't clear from your question.

Comment: I would not simply remove the `NaN` values. You will end up with `numel(fd) ~= numel(v)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are `nan`s in your data, you should definitely ignore them when doing such processing (should those points be 0? -inf? inf? 10.5? pi?). The main point is, as [@IKavanagh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210950/how-to-deal-with-nans-when-using-an-exponential-smoothing-function#comment54226329_33210950) pointed out, that you have to actually ignore those points entirely, i.e. drop the `v` elements as well that correspond to the `nan`s:

```
v = datenum(2008, 1, 1):datenum(2010, 11, 31); % time vector
d = rand(1,length(v)); % data vector

d(10) = nan;

v = v(~isnan(d));
d = d(~isnan(d));

%do the rest of the processing as usual

fd = d;
alpha_o = 0.2;
for ii = 2:length(fd);
    fd(ii) = alpha_o.*fd(ii) + (1-alpha_o).*fd(ii-1);
end

plot(v,d); hold on; plot(v,fd);
```

The fact that `nan`s are present in your data show you that those data points are invalid, so you have to get rid of them for smoothing/fitting (and `plot` will automatically ignore those).